# Print in single line in Python

Tags: python

Given some code:

```
keyword=re.findall(r'ke\w+ = \S+',s)
score=re.findall(r'sc\w+ = \S+',s)
print '%s,%s' %(keyword,score)
```

The output of above code is:

> ['keyword = NORTH', 'keyword = GUESS', 'keyword = DRESSES', 'keyword = RALPH', 'keyword = MATERIAL'],['score = 88466', 'score = 83965', 'score = 79379', 'score = 74897', 'score = 68168']

But I want the format should be different lines like:

```
NORTH,88466
GUESS,83935
DRESSES,83935
RALPH,73379
MATERIAL,68168
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of the last line, do this instead:

```
>>> for k, s in zip(keyword, score):
        kw = k.partition('=')[2].strip()
        sc = s.partition('=')[2].strip()
        print '%s,%s' % (kw, sc)


NORTH,88466
GUESS,83965
DRESSES,79379
RALPH,74897
MATERIAL,68168
```

Here is how it works:

- The [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) brings the corresponding elements together pairwise.
- The [partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) splits a string like `'keyword = NORTH'` into three parts (the part before the equal sign, the equal sign itself, and the part after.  The `[2]` keeps only the latter part.
- The [strip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Alternatively, you can modify your regexes to do much of the work for you by using groups to capture the keywords and scores without the surrounding text:

```
keywords = re.findall(r'ke\w+ = (\S+)',s)
scores = re.findall(r'sc\w+ = (\S+)',s)
for keyword, score in zip(keywords, scores):
    print '%s,%s' %(keyword,score)
```

Comment: Nice. `strip()` isn't necessary if you `partition()` on `' = '` :-)

Comment: BTW if I use a split() instead of partition() here, would there be any difference besides not having the separator in result?

Comment: For your particular data, no. `partition` is often easier to work with in situations where the separator might be absent or appear multiple times, since you'll always get a 3-item list where `split` might throw an exception or give you multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be like would be to [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together (to iterate over them pairwise) and  use [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to grab the data after the `=`, like this::

```
def after_equals(s):
    return s.partition(' = ')[-1]

for k,s in zip(keyword, score):
    print after_equals(k) + ',' + after_equals(s)
```

If you don't want to call `after_equals()` twice, you could refactor to:

```
for pair in zip(keyword, score):
    print ','.join(after_equals(data) for data in pair)
```

If you want to write to a text file (you really should have mentioned this in the question, not in your comments on my answer), then you can take this approach...

```
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as output:
    for pair in zip(keyword, score):
        output.write(','.join(after_equals(data) for data in pair) + '\n')
```

Output:

```
% cat output.txt
NORTH,88466
GUESS,83965
DRESSES,79379
RALPH,74897
MATERIAL,68168
```

Comment: How to write output to a file,                                    FILE.writelines ','.join(after_equals(data) for data in pair)

Comment: Anyone please help,I want the output to write to a file in same format

Comment: @Ryder: If you're not getting the answer that you desire, please update your question rather than add comments to arbitrary answers. I also recommend reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
keyword = ['NORTH','GUESS','DERESSES','RALPH']
score = [88466,83935,83935,73379]

for key,value in zip(keyword,score):
  print "%s,%s" %(key,value)
```